# How to uninstall python 2.7.16 on macOS 10.15.4 Catalina?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.8

I was trying to install the newest version of python, 3.8. But after the installation was complete, I ran

```
python --version

Python 2.7.16
```

Is there a way to get rid of the python 2 that came with macOS? I will need to use python 3.
Or is there a way to switch to python 3 from python 2?

Comment: What about `python3 --version` ?

Comment: You do not want to uninstall the system Python 2. Leave it as is. You can always just use `python3` if you want Python 3, or [create a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and run your apps inside it, where you can use `python` as Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I am not well experienced in MacOs but I think this may help you to upgrade the current version of your python to the newest one

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade python
```